# Nginx ""server" directive is not allowed"

Tags: nginx

I recived this message

root@lolnews2:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/lolnews.com.br:57

this is my conf

```
  server {
        listen 80; ## listen for ipv4;
        #listen [::]:80 default_server  ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name lolnews.com.br;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }
        #sitemap
        location ~ ([^/]*)sitemap(.*)\.x(m|s)l$ {
        rewrite ^/sitemap\.xml$ /sitemap_index.xml permanent;
        rewrite ^/([a-z]+)?-?sitemap\.xsl$ /index.php?xsl=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/sitemap_index\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;


        ## following lines are options. Needed for wordpress-seo addons
        rewrite ^/news_sitemap\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_news last;
        rewrite ^/locations\.kml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_local_kml last;
        rewrite ^/geo_sitemap\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_local last;
        rewrite ^/video-sitemap\.xsl$ /index.php?xsl=video last;

        access_log off;
}
        #fimsitemap
        # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied reques$
        #location /RequestDenied {
        #       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        #}
# You may add here your
# server {
#   ...
# }
# statements for each of your virtual hosts to this file

##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

server {
    listen 80; ## listen for ipv4; 
    #listen [::]:80 default_server  ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name lolnews.com.br;

        location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
        #sitemap
        location ~ ([^/]*)sitemap(.*)\.x(m|s)l$ {
        rewrite ^/sitemap\.xml$ /sitemap_index.xml permanent;
        rewrite ^/([a-z]+)?-?sitemap\.xsl$ /index.php?xsl=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/sitemap_index\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
        rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap$


        ## following lines are options. Needed for wordpress-seo addons
        rewrite ^/news_sitemap\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_news last;
    rewrite ^/locations\.kml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_local_kml last;
    rewrite ^/geo_sitemap\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=wpseo_local last;
    rewrite ^/video-sitemap\.xsl$ /index.php?xsl=video last;

    access_log off;


    #fimsitemap
    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
    #}

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
        location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#   listen 8000;
#   listen somename:8080;
#   server_name somename alias another.alias;
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#   listen 443;
#   server_name localhost;
#
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   ssl on;
#   ssl_certificate cert.pem;
#   ssl_certificate_key cert.key;
#
#   ssl_session_timeout 5m;
#
#   ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
#   ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
#   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: its another error 
i'm really desesperated to make this work out

Comment: Check that your opening (`{`) and closing (`}`) braces are properly matched. Neither of the location directives for sitemap appear to have a closing brace.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
 #sitemap
    location ~ ([^/]*)sitemap(.*)\.x(m|s)l$ {
    rewrite ^/sitemap\.xml$ /sitemap_index.xml permanent;
    rewrite ^/([a-z]+)?-?sitemap\.xsl$ /index.php?xsl=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/sitemap_index\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
    rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap$
```

You are missing ending semicolon after the definition, and closing `}`. Use this:

```
     #sitemap
    location ~ ([^/]*)sitemap(.*)\.x(m|s)l$ {
    rewrite ^/sitemap\.xml$ /sitemap_index.xml permanent;
    rewrite ^/([a-z]+)?-?sitemap\.xsl$ /index.php?xsl=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/sitemap_index\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
    rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap$;
}
```

You should really make sure that you use tabs properly in your configuration file, so that you can see how the configuration elements match.